# Bash randomization function error

Tags: bash, xubuntu

So, I wrote this crap bash script that connects randomly to a vpn server from a pool of 100+ ovpn config files:

```
test {

_OVPNs="/path/to/OVPNs"
_RANDOM=$(shuf -e 1 -n 1 ${_OVPNs}/*)

    sudo openvpn --config ${_RANDOM}
}
```

It works fine most of the time but occasionally produces weird errors:

```
sudo openvpn --config 1
```

or

```
Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: 1
Use --help for more information.
```

Any idea why "1" is occasionally assigned as the result of the shuffle?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting `1` as the output as one of the inputs to `shuf` for shuffling around is `1` (`-e 1 ...`).

You need to pass all the possible elements, by using an array:

```
_ovpns=( /path/to/OVPNs/* )
shuf -e "${ovpns[@]}" -n 1
```

or directly do:

```
shuf -e /path/to/OVPNs/* -n 1
```

Taking the directory name as a variable:

```
_ovpns='/path/to/OVPNs'
shuf -e "${_ovpns}"/* -n 1
```

---

Note that, unless absolutely necessary do not use all uppercases (with underscore) as user defined variable name to avoid potential overwriting of environment variables.

Comment: I don't think you *always* get `1`; at least as tested with coreutils 8.25, it appears to treat all non-option arguments after the `-e` as elements to shuffle i.e. `1` just becomes *one of* the outputs.

Comment: @steeldriver You are right. I stand corrected. Thanks.